# populate object where it contains values from another list

Tags: c#, linq

In my object I have 3 properties:

```
    public String PlaceName{ get; set; }
    public Int32 PlaceId { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
```

I have a result with 5 rows being returns from my database (SQLPlaceALL).

- place A
- place B
- place C
- place D
- place E

These 5 results I always want to display.  However, when I choose a contact, that contact could have one or more of these places in the results returned (sqlPlaceResults).

- place B
- place C
- place D

  ```
      var popPlace = from places in sqlPlaceResults.AsEnumerable()
                       join placeAll in sqlPlaceResultsAll.AsEnumerable() 
                          on places["PLACEID"] equals placeAll["PLACEID"]
                         select new Place
                         {
                             PlaceName = places["NAME"].ToString(),
                             PlaceId = (Int32)places["PLACEID"],
                             Ischecked = true
                         };
  ```

When I do this popPlace only contains the 3 items that sqlPlaceResults contains.  I'd like my display to do something like this:

- place A
- place B - Checked
- place C - Checked
- place D - Checked
- place E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a `left join` it seems.

[Here is an MSDN on how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

And here is your code modified into something similar from the article:

```
var popPlace = 
    from places in sqlPlaceResults.AsEnumerable()
        join placeAll in sqlPlaceResultsAll.AsEnumerable() 
            on places["PLACEID"] equals placeAll["PLACEID"] into placeAllVals
    from sub in placeAllVals.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Place
    {
        PlaceName = regions["NAME"].ToString(),
        PlaceId = (Int32)regions["PLACEID"],
        Ischecked = sub != null
    };
```

Comment: this still only returns 1 result

Comment: Yah, it is acting like a left join. So, if you have the sides backwards, it can definitely make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. You want to query *all* the places, and set `IsChecked` based on whether there are any matching `sqlPlaceResults`.

```
var popPlace = 
    from placeAll in sqlPlaceResultsAll.AsEnumerable()
    select new Place
    {
        placeName = regions["NAME"].ToString(),
        PlaceId = (Int32)regions["PLACEID"],
        Ischecked = sqlPlaceResults.AsEnumerable().Any(
            places => places["PLACEID"] == placeAll["PLACEID"])
    };
```

Comment: I like this answer quite a bit.  This would seem to be a faster query than a left join, do you have any notion on performance of this solution vs a left join? (and hello from SLC :)

Comment: @paqogomez: Unless you've determined that performance is an issue, you should care more about readability; and to me, this is much more readable than a left-join. But yes, this would most likely perform slightly better than a left join, because as soon as it determines that there is a matching place, it can stop searching. But that assumes more than I actually know about the backing data structures--why are we saying .AsEnumerable(), for instance?